# Visual Studio 2012 Crashes while deploying windows phone application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-debugging, windows-phone-toolkit

I am developing a windows phone application and trying to deploy it on Emulator as well as Actual device, whenever I hit debug button Visual Studio crashes and restarts. I also tried o run it with admin privileges.

I have checked event logs and the error is in Phone tools/conman2.dll

and exception is as below:

> Log Name:      Application Application: **devenv.exe** Framework Version:
>   v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled
>   exception. Exception Info: **System.AccessViolationException** Stack:
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop.ConManServerClass.ConnectDevice()
>   at Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Device.Connect()    at
>   Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Wrapper.ConnectivityWrapper11.CreateConnectedDeviceInstance(Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Device)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SmartDevice.MultiTargeting.Connectivity.ConnectableDevice.Connect()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonProject.SmartDevice.Deploy.DeployTask.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.SilverlightMobileVSProjectFlavorCfg.Deploy(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

I am not able to fix the problem I also tried to run **`devenv.exe /resetuserdata`** but no help.

Am I missing on any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to run the application in release mode whenever you want to deploy it in a real device. Look at this video in contains a good explanation
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-8-Understanding-Compilation-and-Deployment

Comment: You can deploy debug version as well on a real device.